# Get bean validation message from spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch and beanValidationItemProcessor() as defined in the documentation.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public BeanValidatingItemProcessor<VendorDTO> beanValidatingItemProcessor() throws Exception {
    BeanValidatingItemProcessor<VendorDTO> beanValidatingItemProcessor = new BeanValidatingItemProcessor<>();
    beanValidatingItemProcessor.setFilter(false);

    return beanValidatingItemProcessor;
}
```

When a validation occurs a `org.springframework.batch.item.validator.ValidationException` is thrown and I'm able to see my field error like so.

> Field error in object 'item' on field 'peid': rejected value []; codes
>   [Size.item.peid,Size.peid,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [item.peid,peid]; arguments []; default message [peid],12,1];
>   default message [size must be between 1 and 12]

How do I get a simple message object resolving the field id and default message?

Comment: I don't understand the question (fully)... which `id`? what do you mean by "resolving..."?  does this go into the right direction: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-custom-validation-message-source ?

Comment: @xerx593 I'm sorry, I meant the field name. I'm going to post an answer to my own question below. Please let me know if you have a better solution. I'm just looking to get a simple message object with the field name, rejected value, and default message.

Answer (score 1):

I've found I've been able to gain access to the field errors by casting the ValidationException getCause() to BindException where I then have access to the field errors.

```
@OnSkipInProcess
public void logSkippedEmail(VendorDTO vendorDTO, Throwable t) {
    JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();

    if (t instanceof ValidationException) {
        ValidationException e = (ValidationException) t;

        if(e.getCause() instanceof BindException) {
            BindException bindException = (BindException) e.getCause();

            List<FieldError> fieldErrors = bindException.getFieldErrors();

            for (FieldError fieldError : fieldErrors) {
                BatchValidation batchValidation = new BatchValidation();

                batchValidation.setDataField(fieldError.getField());
                batchValidation.setRejectedValue(String.valueOf(fieldError.getRejectedValue()));
                batchValidation.setValidationMessage(fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
                batchValidation.setJobInstanceId(jobExecution.getJobId());
                batchValidation.setJobName(jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName());

                batchValidationRepository.save(batchValidation);
            }
        }

    }

}
```